# WP_Query not ordering by title

Tags: wordpress

I try to get all the posts (with a specific custom type) ordered by the title ascending, but the SQL query generated, orders after post_date.
Code:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( 
   array(
      'post_type' => 'member',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC',
    ) 
  );

while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    // get post excerpt
    get_template_part('content/'.get_post_type());
    // wikiwp_get_post_excerpt($post);
}
```

Query:

> SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type =
>   'member' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status
>   = 'closed' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'hidden') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC

I really don't understand why this is happening. I deactivated most of the plugins and tried different combinations and I had no success.

$my_query:

> WP_Query Object ( [query] => Array ( [post_type] => member
>   [posts_per_page] => -1 [orderby] => title [order] => ASC )
>   [query_vars] => Array ( [post_type] => member [posts_per_page] => -1
>   [orderby] => order [order] => ASC [error] => [m] => [p] => 0
>   [post_parent] => [subpost] => [subpost_id] => [attachment] =>
>   [attachment_id] => 0 [name] => [static] => [pagename] => [page_id] =>
>   0 [second] => [minute] => [hour] => [day] => 0 [monthnum] => 0 [year]
>   => 0 [w] => 0 [category_name] => [tag] => [cat] => [tag_id] => [author] => [author_name] => [feed] => [tb] => [paged] => 0 [meta_key]
>   => [meta_value] => [preview] => [s] => [sentence] => [title] => [fields] => [menu_order] => [embed] => [category__in] => Array ( )
>   [category__not_in] => Array ( ) [category__and] => Array ( )
>   [post__in] => Array ( ) [post__not_in] => Array ( ) [post_name__in] =>
>   Array ( ) [tag__in] => Array ( ) [tag__not_in] => Array ( ) [tag__and]
>   => Array ( ) [tag_slug__in] => Array ( ) [tag_slug__and] => Array ( ) [post_parent__in] => Array ( ) [post_parent__not_in] => Array ( )
>   [author__in] => Array ( ) [author__not_in] => Array ( )
>   [ignore_sticky_posts] => [suppress_filters] => [cache_results] => 1
>   [update_post_term_cache] => 1 [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
>   [update_post_meta_cache] => 1 [nopaging] => 1 [comments_per_page] =>
>   50 [no_found_rows] => ) [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object ( [queries]
>   => Array ( ) [relation] => AND [table_aliases:protected] => Array ( ) [queried_terms] => Array ( ) [primary_table] => wp_posts
>   [primary_id_column] => ID ) [meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object (
>   [queries] => Array ( ) [relation] => [meta_table] => [meta_id_column]
>   => [primary_table] => [primary_id_column] => [table_aliases:protected] => Array ( ) [clauses:protected] => Array ( ) [has_or_relation:protected] => ) [date_query] => [request] => SELECT
>   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'member'
>   AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status =
>   'closed' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private' OR wp_posts.post_status =
>   'hidden') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC ))

Answer (score 12):

Your code looks right. I would look to see if you have any code elsewhere, such as a filter altering the output of the query that you created. Sounds like you might have something like that because your post loop is correct.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'member',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();

        get_template_part('content/'.get_post_type());
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a post ordering plugin installed that was interfering and your comment reminded me about it.

Comment: you could have marked it as the correct answer because it helped you resolve the issue, lol!

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue. I solved it using 'post_title' instead of 'title'.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( 
   array(
      'post_type' => 'member',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'post_title',
      'order' => 'ASC'
    ) 
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Below code :

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( 
   array(
      'post_type' => 'member',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC'
    ) 
  );
```

You have added `,` at last after `ASC` so i think the issue was.then `$my_query` is where your array is so then just loop through that like below to get result as you wanted.

```
while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
//Your post code here to get post attributes
endwhile;wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Adding an additional comma to the last element of a PHP array will not have any effect during execution.